# S3 based file system capable of requesting only part of file

Tags: filesystems, amazon-s3, s3fs

I'm storing large datasets in s3, but on a given computer in my cluster, my program only needs  to read a small subset of the data.

I first tried s3fs, but it downlooads the entire file first, which takes a really long time.

Are there any s3 backed file systems that make use of the S3 API *bytes* parameter, so that internal read (and seek) commands only read the desired part of the file?

As a practical example if I run:

> tail -c 1024 huge_file_on_s3

only the last 1kb should be requested (via the bytes parameter), meaning I should get the result really fast.

(I am not concerned with writing back to S3; only reading from it)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HTTP Range to fetch a byte-range from an S3 file, this is the documented way to achieve this in the [S3 API docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html).
A library that can help is [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto), written in python. With boto, you can do something like:

```
tempfile = open(tempFilePath, 'wb')
S3Key.get_contents_to_file(tempfile, headers={'Range': 'bytes=0-100000'}
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788290/boto-get-byte-range-returns-more-than-expected

If you can replace the need to have a filesystem with a python program or similar, it will work best. S3 is not meant to be used like a filesystem, and tools like s3fs are frowned upon. I've used s3fs in production for a while and it's always been more trouble than it's worth. It's good for non-critical parts, but is not posix-compliant. Also, I can't imagine you will find a tool that exposes S3's HTTP API.

However, while looking into recent s3fs issues, I found that if you turn off cache (use_cache option), then s3fs won't download the entire file.
Issue: https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/source/detail?r=458
The [latest s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) seems to have use_cache off by default.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine most servers would support the HTTP Range headers.  'bytes' sounds like it's an internal S3 only feature, while Range headers are supported by every modern webserver I'm aware of.